# Classification of principal divisors on complex elliptic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Proposition VI.3.4 in Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* proves that for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ (given as a lattice $\Lambda$), any divisor $D$ of degree $0$ such that the sum of the divisor summed as points in $\mathbb{C}$ lies in $\Lambda$ is principal.

I am confused on the first step in the proof: Let $n_1, \dots, n_r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $z_1, \dots, z_r \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\sum n_i = 0$ and $\sum n_i z_i \in \Lambda$. Silverman has already constructed a function $\sigma$ whose zeros are exactly the points $\Lambda$, all with order 1. He then says:

> Let $\lambda = \sum n_i z_i \in \Lambda$. Replacing $n_1 (z_1) + \cdots + n_r (z_r)$ by $n_1(z_1) + \cdots + n_r (z_r) + (0) - (\lambda)$, we may assume that $\sum n_i z_i = 0$,

and goes on to define $f(z) = \prod \sigma(z - z_i)^{n_i}$, which has the correct zeros and poles. I don't see why this first step of reducing to the case that $\sum n_i z_i = 0$ is necessary. Since we already know the zeros of $\sigma(z)$, we know that the zeros of $\sigma(z - z_i)$ are at exactly the points $z_i + \Lambda$, and all have order $1$, so the function $f(z)$ has the correct zeros and poles. Why do we need to reduce to the case that $\sum n_i z_i = 0$?

Comment: If $f$ doesn't have degree $0$, it will have a zero/pole at infinity.

Comment: Maybe my complex analysis is too rusty, but it's not clear to me why $\sum n_i z_i = 0$ determines whether $f(z)$ has a pole or zero at infinity. Could you elaborate?

Comment: That sum is exactly the total degree of the function $f$.
Think about the behavior of the three functions $z$, $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{z}{1+z}$ as $z\to \infty$.

Comment: Maybe I have the wrong definition of "degree" - I thought the degree would be the sum of the order of f over all points, so in this case the degree would be $\sum n_i$ rather than $\sum n_i z_i$? We are already requiring that $\sum n_i = 0$, so where does $\sum n_i z_i = 0$ come in? Sorry for being obtuse :(

Comment: For the three functions you give, I see that the first has a pole at $\infty$, the second has a zero, and the third has neither, and that this corresponds to the first having degree $1$, the second $-1$ and the final $0$, but even if we don't have $\sum n_i z_i = 0$, we still have $\sum n_i = 0$, so since the order of the zeros and poles at each $z_i$ is $n_i$, don't we still have that the degree of $f$ is $\sum n_i = 0$?

Comment: Oh I see. You are not being obtuse at all. I misunderstood your confusion. I'll have to read that part of the proof in Silverman more carefully.

Comment: Okay, I had a chance to go through my Silverman. Please look at the penultimate line of the proof which computes $\frac{f(z+\omega)}{f(z)}$ for $\omega \in \Lambda$. This is simplified to $e^{(az+b)\sum n_i}e^{-a(\sum n_iz_i)}$ which is equal to $1$ if we have that both $\sum n_iz_i$ and $\sum n_i$ are $0$.

Comment: This part is, of course, key for the function $f$ to have $\Lambda$-invariance.

Comment: Oh I see - the way it was written I assumed that $\sum n_i z_i = 0$ was necessary for $f$ to have the right divisor (just because he puts this immediately before the part about the divisor of $f$), but actually we only need it to make sure that $f$ has the right periods. That makes sense, thank you!